# How to use the RenderedTargetBitmap after update the view in uwp?

Tags: uwp, rendertargetbitmap

I have the scroll viewer to zoom the image and I zoomed the image and made some changes in the image. Then, I am trying to save an image in button click. In the button click, I have changed the Zoom factor value to 1 and then use the RenderedTargetBitmap class to get the stream of the scroll viewer.

Now I get the zoomed area values only, not able to get the changes which I made the button click. I know RenderedTagetBitmap only return the visible values, but I want the zoomed out values. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I get the zoomed area values only, not able to get the changes which I made the button click.

By testing on my side, if as you described, changed the zoom factor to 1, the `RenderedTagetBitmap` can get the whole image correctly which is showed inside `ScrollViewer`  when zoom factor is 1, not only the zoomed area. Here is the simple testing code:

```
private async void btnsave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (RenderedScroll.ChangeView(0, 0, 1, true))
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderedScroll, width, height);
        RenderedImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
    }
}
```

But if I didn't disable the animation of `ChangeView` method, the `RenderedTagetBitmap` may only take the zoomed area which is same to you. This is caused by that the `RenderedTagetBitmap` take the content of `ScrollViewer` before `ScrollViewer` completed changing view to factor 1 since the changing view animation need a while to complete. In that case, you may wait for a while for the animation playing.

```
private async void btnsave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (RenderedScroll.ChangeView(0, 0, 1))
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderedScroll, width, height);
        RenderedImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
    } 
}
```

Or just disable the `ChangeView` animation as the first code block showed if you didn't need that.